# Find area under the following curves.

Tags: calculus

Find the area under the curves :

1.$$x^2+y^2 \le 100 $$

2.$$\sin (x+y)\gt0$$

My Attempt:

I tried what I knew. Which is, trying to graph it and using basic integration and trying to find the area. But I was under the impression that-

$\sin (x+y)\gt0 \Rightarrow x+y\gt\arcsin0 \Rightarrow x+y\gt 0$

When my answer didn't match, I checked why and saw this weird patchy graph and I realised where I went wrong. The link is attached below:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b9jnct7ik0

I have no idea how to proceed with this. Help required. Thanks!

Also, it might be helpful to note that  this is an MCQ. So, (if it helps,) the options are :

(A) $25\pi$

(B) $50\pi$

(C) $50$

(D) $100\pi − 50$

Comment: Your impression that $\sin (x+y)\gt0 \Rightarrow x+y\gt\arcsin0 \Rightarrow x+y\gt 0$ is false. In fact, one can only conclude that $2k\pi<x+y<(2k+1)\pi$ for some integer $k$. And your weird graph, in my humble opinion, is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the area of region $R$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2479557/how-to-find-the-area-of-region-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly (I'm not sure what "under the curves" means) then note from your picture that the area required is exactly $\frac 12$ of the area of the circle $$= \pi \frac{10^2}2 = 50 \pi.$$

Comment: My bad. The exact question is "Consider the region $R =${$(x, y) : x^2+y^2 ≤ 100, \sin(x+y) > 0$}$. What is the area of R?". Is the area of R half the area of the circle as an approximation or is it really half the area of the circle? Also, how can we find the area without drawing the graph/having no idea how the graph look like?

Comment: Now that you pointed it out, it appears that for all $a>0$, where equation of circle is $x^2+y^2 \le a $, the area of $R$ is half the area of the circle. But, can we find the area without knowing what the graph looks like?

Comment: I don't see a way to find the answer without at least thinking graphically.

Comment: That seems about right. Thanks.