# What is the area of the region $R$ if $R=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\le100$, $\sin(x+y)>0\}$?

Tags: geometry, inequality

$x^2+y^2\le100 \implies $ a circle with radius 10 and the region enclosed within.

Now given, $sin(x+y)>0 \implies y>-x$

Also we know $sin(x+y)\le1 \implies x+y\le \dfrac{\pi}{2} \implies y\le-x+\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

From this we get the area of the required region is an isosceles triangle with two equal sides $=10 $ which is the radius of the circle and the height of the triangle is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Thus reqd. area = $\dfrac{1}{2}\times \dfrac{\pi}{2}\times 2\cdot \sqrt{100-\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}}$.

Now the answer to this question is $50\pi$

Now my question is how are they arriving at it?

Clearly I must have committed mistakes. Please tell me where I am wrong and give me the correct solution please.

Comment: "From this we get the area of the required region is an isosceles triangle": if those implications were true - *and they aren't* -, the best you could make out of them would be that the required region is **inside** and isosceles triangle, not that it is the triangle itself. As for why the implications are not true, notice that $\sin(x+y)<1$ for $x=0$ and $y=-50$, as well as $\sin(x+y)>0$ for $x=0$ and $y=-\frac32\pi$.

Comment: Users one request please no need to upvote or downvote the attempts. See with constant downvotes, be it intentional or otherwise bans the user to ask questions. I believe I haven't posted anything that is worth no effort and hence all the downvotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the area of region $R$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2479557/how-to-find-the-area-of-region-r)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By symmetry, assuming uniform distribution over the circle with radius $10$, $$Pr(\sin(x+y)>0)=Pr(\sin(x+y)<0)=\frac12$$

Hence the area is 
$$\pi \frac{(10)^2}2=50\pi$$

[image]

Note that $\sin(x+y) > 0 $ does not imply $x+y >0$.

Comment: Very neat argument! And if I follow you correctly, this means that for any radius $r>0$, the area of $\{(x,y):\sin(x+y)>0, x^2+y^2\leq r^2\}$ is precisely $\pi r^2/2$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. as you move along $x+y =c$ there is a corresponding line $x+y = -c$ that will give you a different sign as you substitute it in the sine function. Also, note that $\sin(x+y)=0$ is measure $0$.

Comment: Just by curiosity, does the same argument hold if we replace $\sin$ by $f$ where $f$ is any continuous odd function?

Comment: I think we should be careful to check if $f(x+y)=0$ having measure $0$ conditions holds in this case. For example if $f$ is the zero function, then it doesn't work. If the condition holds, I think we do have that result.  If not, we have to subtract away the region where we take value $0$ then divide it by $2$.

Comment: It was a duplicate.