# Find area of region R

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry, area

Region $R$ contains all the points $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2 \le 100$ and $ \sin (x+y) \ge 0$. Find the area of region $R$.

I can't seem to proceed except for the fact that the inequalities give that $x$ and $y$ do not exceed $10$ and their sum isn't a multiple of $π$

Help would be appreciated. There was an answer provided earlier(on StackExchange), but I couldn't understand much from it and would like an explicit solution.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hint: Under the map $(x,y) \mapsto (-x,-y)$, the region $x^2 + y^2 \le 100$ is invariant while $\sin(x+y)$ picks up a minus sign, this means...

Comment: Are you able to graph your region $R$?

Comment: @achillehui Umm, half the points aren't in the graph, I guess?

Comment: Yup, aside from a set of measure zero (i.e those lines of the form $x+y = k \pi$ for integer $k$), half of the points inside the circle of radius $10$ belongs to $R$ and the other half doesn't.

Comment: @Sen47 Yes, but you can figure out the area of this region and make it double. I should have written `what the region will be`.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, helped me a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the area of region $R$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2479557/how-to-find-the-area-of-region-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Now you can figure out what the regions will be (@achille hui's hint.)

Comment: It was a duplicate.

Comment: @AnneBauval duplicate of what?

Comment: For instance of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2479557/how-to-find-the-area-of-region-r as commented above, but also of sevetal posts linked to it.

Comment: Okay, I see! Sorry, while answering I did not see.