# Consider the region $R=\{(x,y):x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 100, \sin (x+y)>0\}.$ What is the area of $R$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, alternative-proof

Consider the region $R=\{(x,y):x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 100, \sin (x+y)>0\}.$ What is the area of $R$ ?

If we take a look at it's graph, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b9jnct7ik0, it easily follows, from the symmetry that the area is half of the area of the circle. But my point, is, to solve this problem, I think approaching it graphically , seems more reasonable. So, I tried sketching the graph without a graphing calculator. The graph of the inequality, $x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 100$ is trivial to sketch. However, the problem comes with the inequality, $\sin(x+y)>0\implies 2k\pi\lt x\lt (2k+1)\pi,$ of which the graph I am neither able to visualise nor able to sketch.

Are there any ways to predict the graph of this inequalities using elementary ways?

If no such method exists, I am interested, in an alternative approach to this problem, which doesn't rely on graphs/graphing calculator.

Comment: does this answer your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2479557/how-to-find-the-area-of-region-r

Comment: Notice that your implication $\sin(x+y) > 0$ actually implies that for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $2\pi k < x+y< (2k +1)\pi$.  You can rewrite this inequality as $2 \pi k - x < y < (2k+1) k - x.$  This means that the region you are looking are all the areas between the slanted lines $y = 2\pi k -x, y = (2k+1) \pi - x$.  You can see these lines in the post linked by the user above me.  This also helps you see that half the circle is covered by these regions.

Comment: @Restless How did you find this? This never appeared in search results of this site and neither in approach zero?

Comment: @StephenSmith This post is a FAQ: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24x%5E2%2By%5E2%5Cle100%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csin%5Cleft(x%2By%5Cright)%5Cge0%24&p=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got
$$\sin(x+y)>0\implies 2k\pi\lt x+y\lt (2k+1)\pi$$
which gives
$$y>2k\pi - x$$
and
$$y<(2k+1)\pi -x$$
These two are just straight lines and hence fairly easy to draw or visualize.

Comment: It was a (multi)duplicate.